# Laravel 4 Auth::attempt() issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying the Laravel's Auth class but the method returns false always. Here's my code:

Controller :

```
public function postLogin()
    {
        // Declare the rules for the form validation.
        //
        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'Required|Email',
            'password' => 'Required'
        );

        // Get all the inputs.
        //
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        // Validate the inputs.
        //
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // Check if the form validates with success.
        //
        if ($validator->passes())
        {
                   //echo $password; displays test
            // Try to log the user in.
            //
            if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
            {


                // Redirect to the users page.
                //
                return Redirect::to('account')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                // Redirect to the login page.
                //
                return Redirect::to('account/login')->with('error', 'Email/password invalid.');
            }
        }

        // Something went wrong.
        //
        return Redirect::to('account/login')->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag());
    }
```

Seeder.php

public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->delete();

```
$users = array(
    array(
        'email'      => 'test@test.com',
        'password'   => Hash::make('test'),
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name'  => 'Doe',
        'created_at' => new DateTime,
        'updated_at' => new DateTime,
    )
);

DB::table('users')->insert( $users );
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you are getting $email and $password? and check your database using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ya i'm getting them !

Comment: You are getting account/login with validation errors or Email/password invalid ?

Comment: I get Email/password invalid error

Comment: may be because of framework bug. So try to update framework using composer update

Answer (score 1):

It will be because of framework bug. So try to update it.

```
composer update
```

Or

```
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 1):

In your config/auth.php file
try changing from 'driver' => 'eloquent' to 'driver' => 'database'.